# Matrix4 to GLSL uniform value

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

So I'm creating a simple game in C++ with OpenGL API (Using SDL2 and GLEW).

I created simple shader program, and I started creating uniform variable loaders (Like a Vector3, float) but I really don't know how to load 4x4 Matrix to uniform variable with `glUniformMatrix4fv`.

How to put those values from my Matrix4 to this function?

Comment: You just give it a pointer to the matrix, what's the problem?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342594/passing-uniform-4x4-matrix-to-vertex-shader-program

Comment: So what should I put inside "count" value, I guess false is going to "transpose" value and the next variable is value. But how should I put it inside this function? Create F32 mat[3][3]; and put mat inside this function?

Comment: @skprime glUniformMatrix4fv expects a 4x4 matrix

Comment: mat[3][3] = 4x4 matrix. Because we have to count from 0.

Comment: @skprime eh no the 3 in the declaration of the static array is the length of it (where 0 is the empty array and 1 has 1 element).

Comment: I created my matrix like this and it works fine.

Comment: that's undefined behavior and you are probably thrashing some other poor struct's data.

Comment: @skprime that means the index goes from zero to size minus one, the size is not size plus one (obviously, because what does that even mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glUniformMatrix4fv expects a pointer to a buffer with 16 floats.

```
float[16] m1;
struct mat4{
    float m00, m01, m02, m03;
    float m10, m11, m12, m13;
    float m20, m21, m22, m23;
    float m30, m31, m32, m33;
};
mat4 m2
```

The following are all valid:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatUniformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m2);
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatUniformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, m1);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.gl/gl4/glUniform):

> *count*
>
> For the matrix (**glUniformMatrix***) commands, specifies the number of
>   matrices that are to be modified. This should be 1 if the targeted
>   uniform variable is not an array of matrices, and 1 or more if it is
>   an array of matrices.
>
> [...]
>
> *value*
>
> For the vector and matrix commands, specifies a pointer to an array of count values that will be used to update the specified
>   uniform variable.